# Is there a way to compare variables in a class

Tags: python

I'm having a problem with comparing variables in a class I made

when I call `print(t2.between(t1, t3))`

This is the error I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "e:\CS-OOP-Fall 2023\Classtest1.py", line 18, in <module>
    print(t2.between(t1, t3)) # is t2 between t1 and t3 as a method
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "e:\CS-OOP-Fall 2023\MyTime.py", line 81, in between
    return (t1 < self < t3)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'MyTime' and 'MyTime'
```

Here is the class:

```py
class MyTime:

    def __init__(self, hrs=0, mins=0, secs=0):

        """ Create a new MyTime object initialized to hrs, mins, secs.
           The values of mins and secs may be outside the range 0-59,
           but the resulting MyTime object will be normalized.
        """

       # Calculate total seconds to represent
        totalsecs = hrs*3600 + mins*60 + secs
        self.hours = totalsecs // 3600        # Split in h, m, s
        leftoversecs = totalsecs % 3600
        self.minutes = leftoversecs // 60
        self.seconds = leftoversecs % 60

    def __str__(self):
        # 0 - hours, 1 - minutes, 2 - seconds
        return ("{0}:{1}:{2}".format(self.hours, self.minutes, self.seconds))  

    def add_time(self, t2):

        h = self.hours + t2.hours
        m = self.minutes + t2.minutes
        s = self.seconds + t2.seconds

        while s >= 60:
            s -= 60
            m += 1

        while m >= 60:
            m -= 60
            h += 1

        sum_t = MyTime(h, m, s)
        return sum_t 
    
    def increment(self, seconds):
        self.seconds += seconds

        while self.seconds >= 60:
            self.seconds -= 60
            self.minutes += 1

        while self.minutes >= 60:
            self.minutes -= 60
            self.hours += 1  

    def to_seconds(self):
        """ Return the number of seconds represented
            by this instance
        """
        return self.hours * 3600 + self.minutes * 60 + self.seconds
    
    def after(self, t2, t3):
        """ Return True if I am strictly greater than both t2 and t3
        """
        if self.hours > t2.hours and self.hours > t3.hours:
            return True
        if self.hours < t2.hours or self.hours < t3.hours:
            return False

        if self.minutes > t2.minutes and self.minutes > t3.minutes:
            return True
        if self.minutes < t2.minutes or self.minutes < t3.minutes:
            return False

        if self.seconds > t2.seconds and self.seconds > t3.seconds:
            return True
        if self.seconds < t2.seconds or self.seconds < t3.seconds:
            return False

        return False

    
    def between(self, t1, t3):
        """Checks if one of the specified times falls between
           another the other times with True or False as a indicator
        """
        # this will cover both cases
        return (t1 < self < t3)
```

I tried a couple things but none of them worked, I tried other parts of the variable but it doesn't seem to work right

In the end I want it to say `True` or `False` based off the time you choose to check but I wanted to see if something else worked first.

Comment: You have to implement the [special methods for comparisons](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__le__).

Comment: I don't think I've seen that before,  is there another way to solve the problem or is that the only way?

Comment: The other way to solve the problem is to use objects from the [datetime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) library, which already have methods for basically everything that you're trying to implement yourself here.

Answer (score 1):

What is the value of a `MyClass` instance? which one of all its attributes is the one to use when evaluating `my_class_instance_1 > my_class_instance_2`?

You have to use the magic method `__lt__` to indicate python how to make a comparison:

```
from datetime import datetime

class MyTime:
    def __lt__(self, other):
        my_time = datetime.strptime("%H:%M:%S", f"{self.hours}:{self.minutes}:{self.seconds}")
        other_time = datetime.strptime("%H:%M:%S", f"{other.hours}:{other.minutes}:{other.seconds}")
        return my_time < other_time
```

Comment: you're welcome. I'll appreciate if you choose my answer.

Comment: btw, this will only solve half of the problem:  `t1 < self < t3` won't work even you have implemented `__lt__`

Comment: You need to implement `__gt__` as well, since the expression `t1 < self < t3` is evaluated as `t1 < self and self < t3` (as said in [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons) ), which corresponds to a `__lt__` followed by a `__gt__`

Answer (score 1):

As other people mentioned, `t1 < self` won't work because you have not implemented `__lt__` method.

However, `__lt__` has nothing to do with what you want to do.

Your problem lies in

```
def after(self, t2, t3):
    
def between(self, t1, t3):
```

Implementing these functions do not require those `__lt__` etc functions.  There are several hints for you:

1. You should have write a compare method to compare `self` with another `MyTime`, which means something like this

   ```
   def after(self, other):
       # leave the implementation to you. One simplest way is to
       # make use of to_seconds you implemented
   ```
2. With such method, your "sophiscated" after-2-time and between-2-time method is as simple as:

   ```
   # pseudo code
   def after_all(self, t1, t2):
       return self is after t1 AND self is after t2

   def between(self, t1, t2):
       return (self is after t1 AND self is before t2) or
              (self is after t2 AND self is before t1)
   ```